# How do you re-adjust gaze coordinates after bad eye tracking calibration using Matlab?

Tags: neuroscience, vision, imaging

As a beginner with oculometric data pre-processing (in children from 2 to 12 years old), I would want some advice from the community! :)

Using a Tobii Pro Fusion Eye tracker (250Hz), children are asked to watch stimuli like objects, avatars, and faces (4s per stimulus). My goal is to calculate, in a series of areas of interest which correspond to an x-y coordinate range for each trial, when and where the first fixation occurred, the duration of the first fixation, and the total visit duration/the total time spent of each corresponding AOI, for example. AOIs are, for example, the nose, the mouth, and the eyes of faces.

As I work with young children, I sometimes have lousy calibration (even with our best effort with the child!), and the recording takes place without calibration or with "bad calibration".

With Matlab, I am trying to re-adjust the gaze position to be the most loyal to where the child looks during the apparition of the stimuli because "bad calibration" affects where the children look.

I was wondering if the best way was to either re-adjust the gaze position as a function of the precision and validation (in degree) of the calibration or as a function of the interstim, considering that children look at it correctly (the interstim is a black cross appearing 2 to 3s before the stimuli).

As I am new to this, I am all ears for some tips :)

Thanks to all the community for future advice!

Best, Camille

Comment: Unfortunately I worry that not many people in this community will have expertise here! Which is too bad as it's a good question. However, there is a [Neuroscience Stack Exchange](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/search?q=eye+tracker) that seems to have a variety of questions/answers on this topic. I'm going to flag your question for migration there.